# Where are the Nuxtjs logs on production?

Tags: nuxt.js

I got an error which only occurred in online prod mode.

[image: An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.]

Where is the `your logs` for prod Nuxt.js?

I checked the [document](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/nuxt#debug-logs) but it didn't mentioned it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a server error, you probably need to see on the platform itself and not on Nuxt.
Usually, platforms do have the logs somewhere in the dashboard or you can find it via a CLI (like on Heroku).

Also, this also depends of where your errors are coming from.

---

Maybe sometimes, the frontend can send some errors back to the backend. But usually, it stays totally silent since it is an SPA at the end.
Services like [Sentry.io](https://sentry.io/welcome/) or [Logrocket](https://logrocket.com/) can help you debug and spot those errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally, I figure out that it was caused by wrong nginx configs. But I still wonder if errors occurred in prod mode Nuxt.js, where the errors will be logged?